# Sharepoint web services - allowing/enabling content types programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary, contenttype

I have a site created and I am adding, programmatically via Sharepoint 2010 webservices, content types for a document library.  I am able to do this however I would like also to enable/allow content types for the document library - the code is as follows:-

```
    Lists.Lists lists = new Lists.Lists();
    lists.Url = sharepointWebSiteUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
    lists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    // Create document library templateid 101 is a document library
    System.Xml.XmlNode result = lists.AddList(documentLibraryName, documentLibraryName, 101);
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode xnProperties = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "List", "");

    //Allow/enable content types for the document library
    XmlAttribute xnAllowContentTypesAttribute = (XmlAttribute)xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Attribute, "AllowContentTypes", "");
    xnAllowContentTypesAttribute.Value = "True";
    xnProperties.Attributes.Append(xnAllowContentTypesAttribute);

    XmlAttribute xnContentTypesEnabledAttribute = (XmlAttribute)xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Attribute, "ContentTypesEnabled", "");
    xnContentTypesEnabledAttribute.Value = "True";
    xnProperties.Attributes.Append(xnContentTypesEnabledAttribute);

    XmlNode updateList = lists.UpdateList(documentLibraryName, xnProperties, null, null, null, null);

    //Add the content types
    XmlNode xmlNodeContentType = null;
    xmlNodeContentType = lists.ApplyContentTypeToList(sharepointWebSiteUrl, Constants.ReportDocumentLibraryContentTypeId, documentLibraryName);
    xmlNodeContentType = lists.ApplyContentTypeToList(sharepointWebSiteUrl, Constants.DataSourceDocumentLibraryContentTypeId, documentLibraryName);
    xmlNodeContentType = lists.ApplyContentTypeToList(sharepointWebSiteUrl, Constants.ModelDocumentLibraryContentTypeId, documentLibraryName);
```

The above creates the document library and adds the content types, but does not allow/enable content types for the document library.

A reminder, I need to do this via web services - *not* via the object model

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms415091.aspx) you should try `EnableContentTypes` attribute name.